# Edit and Delete a Text File's Row on GridView (VB .Net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, text-files

I have a gridview that contains value of every rows read from a text file. What I want to do is, edit and delete the selected row on the gridview. I already have the code to show every row on the textfile:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVAnnouncement" runat="server" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="True" EmptyDataText="- No file saved -">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No.">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Container.DisplayIndex + 1%>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

On the Code Behind:

```
'''''Read every row then show it on gridview'''''

' Declarations  
Dim objStreamReader As New StreamReader(Server.MapPath("Announcement.txt"))
Dim arrText As New ArrayList

' Loop through the file and add each line to the ArrayList  
Do While objStreamReader.Peek() >= 0
    arrText.Add(objStreamReader.ReadLine)
Loop

' Close the reader  
objStreamReader.Close()

' Bind the results to the GridView  
GVAnnouncement.DataSource = arrText
GVAnnouncement.DataBind()
```

What I am going to ask is, how do I get the index of selected row return and fill the value to the textbox then update it to the textfile? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Arion: This is intent for ASP .Net..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion first: a file normally is not the best storage. You might consider to use a [dbms](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) instead.

If you want to edit/delete lines in a file, probably the easiest is to create all lines again.
You can store the index for example in a `HiddenField`.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenIndex" Value="<%# Container.DataItem.Index %>" />
    <asp:Label ID="LblAnnouncement" Text="<%# Container.DataItem.Announcement %>" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>

Dim allAnnouncements = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("Announcement.txt"))
Dim source = allAnnouncements.Select(Function(l, index) New With {.Index = index, .Announcement = l}).ToList

' Bind the results to the GridView  
GVAnnouncement.DataSource = source 
GVAnnouncement.DataBind()
```

Then you can edit/delete them in the following way:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)  
    Dim grid = DirectCast(sender, GridView)
    Dim index = Int32.Parse(DirectCast(grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("HiddenIndex"), HiddenField).Value)
    Dim oldAnnamouncement = e.OldValues(0).ToString
    Dim newAnnouncement = e.NewValues(0).ToString
    If Not oldAnnamouncement.Equals(newAnnouncement) Then
        Dim allAnnouncements = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("Announcement.txt"))
        allAnnouncements(index) = newAnnouncement
        IO.File.WriteAllLines(Server.MapPath("Announcement.txt"), allAnnouncements)
    End If

    'Reset the edit index.
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1

    'Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData()
End Sub



Protected Sub GridView1_RowDeleting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs)
    Dim grid = DirectCast(sender, GridView)
    Dim index = Int32.Parse(DirectCast(grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("HiddenIndex"), HiddenField).Value)

    Dim allAnnouncements = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("Announcement.txt"))
    IO.File.WriteAllLines(Server.MapPath("Announcement.txt"), allAnnouncements.Where(Function(l, i) index <> i))

    'Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData()
End Sub
```

Comment: I am consider to use textfile for saving the data because it is light and easy to move everywhere rather than using dbms. I have tried your code but it resulted the row showed twice on the column. There is no redundant on the code, right?: `{.Index = index, .Announcement = l}`. Btw, how to show only the row > 0?

Comment: If you are going to use a text file for storage, be sure to consider the effects of multiple users editing the file at the same time. You dont want to lose your whole file cause  two  users deleted a row at the same time or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use void `RowDeleted`. I would store something in the Datakeys that identify the row. The you can use that `keys` in the `RowDeleted` and do what ever you want. Like this:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVAnnouncement" DataKeyNames="ID" runat="server" 
onrowdeleted="GVAnnouncement_RowDeleted" ...
```

**CS**

```
Sub GVAnnouncement_RowDeleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewDeletedEventArgs)
   e.Keys("ID")
End Sub
```

Find the ID in the file and remove the row and then bind the grid again

Comment: Hi Arion, thanks for the idea. I will try it and tell the result soon :)